# C# Check every other character is a '0'

Tags: c#, string, for-loop

I'm reading in a text file using BinaryReader, then doing what I want with it (stripping characters, etc..), then writing it out using BinaryWriter.

Nice and simple.

One of the things I need to do before I strip anything is to:

1. Check that the amount of characters in the file is even (obviously file.Length % 2) and
2. If the length is even, check that every preceding character is a zero.

For example:

```
0, 10, 0, 20, 0, 30, 0, 40.
```

I need to verify that every second character is a zero.

Any ideas? Some sort of clever for loop?

OKAY!

I need to be a lot more clear about what I'm doing. I have file.txt that contains 'records'. Let's just say it's a comma delimited file. Now, What my program needs to do is read through this file, byte by byte, and strip all of the characters we don't want. I have done that. But, some of the files that will be going through this program will be single byte, and some will be double byte. I need to deal with both of these possibilities. But, I need to figure out whether the file is single or double byte in the first place.

Now, obviously if the file is double byte:

1. The file length will be divisible by 2 and
2. Every preceding character will be a zero.

and THAT'S why I need to do this.

I hope this clears some stuff up..

UPDATE!

I'm just going to have a boolean in the arguments - is16Bit. Thanks for your help guys! I would have rather deleted the question but it won't let me..

Comment: This means that a valid file format contains only integers, right?

Comment: No, sorry, that was just me giving an example. I'm actually reading in bytes, that's why I used numbers there, i was thinking in terms of decimal representations of characters. I totally should have put that in the question, sorry!

Comment: You're reading in BINARY, but talking about characters. The file contains binary numbers or textual numbers?

Comment: Why are you reading a _text_ file with `BinaryReader`?

Comment: It contains all characters.. Letters, numbers..

Comment: Because I need to work with it in bytes.

Comment: So you want to read a UTF-16 encoded file but support only code-points from ASCII(i.e. <128)? Sounds strange to me. You know that in UTF16 encoded files "double byte" the second byte is only 0 for ascii characters.

Comment: So what you actually want to do is writing an encoding detector for UTF-16 vs ANSI or UTF-8?

Comment: Is there no Byte order mark in the double byte files? I think it sounds better to detect the coding and then read the files as text. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/DetectEncoding.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this in a static class:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EveryOther(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
   bool send = true;
   foreach(var item in list)
   {
      if (send) yield return item;
      send = !send;
   }
}
```

and then (using the namespace of the previous class)

```
bool everyOtherIsZero = theBytes.EveryOther().All(c => c == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] foo = file.text.Split(new{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for(int i=0; i<foo .Length; i+=2)
{
  if(file[i]!="0")
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\test.txt");
if (content.Length % 2 != 0)
    throw new Exception("not even");
for(int i = 0; i < content.Length; i+=2)
    if (content[i] != '0')
        throw new Exception("no zero found");
```